# Что лучше: поле полной суммы заказа в таблице или же подсчет по цене каждого товара?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Есть таблица `orders`, есть `order_products`, М-М, все как обычно.  В таблице `order_products` дополнительно дублируются данные о товаре, дабы при изменении цены на товар уже завершенные сделки остались целыми.

Насколько хорошая практика сделать в `orders` поле `amount`, куда считать всю сумму сделки? Сейчас сделал такую функцию в модели Order:

```
public function getTotalPriceAttribute()
{
       $total = 0;
       foreach ($this->products as $product) {
           $total += $product->pivot->amount;
       }
       return $total;
}
```

Но что, если мне нужно получить сделки с самой большой суммой? Правилен ли такой подход?

Comment: *Насколько хорошая практика сделать в orders поле amount, куда считать всю сумму сделки?* В общем случае - плохая. *что, если мне нужно получить сделки с самой большой суммой?* Если это нужно часто - тогда да, можно пойти на переопределение. Но поле суммы использовать исключительно для этого запроса (ответственность при неточности в сумме в данном случае невелика), а в ответственных случаях (например, при показе заказа с общей суммой клиенту, тем более при оплате) всё равно считать его.

Comment: Я бы скорее задался вопросом каковы классы которые будут отвечать за корзину, заказ, скидку, сумму доставки и т.д, и продумал бы как ты это будешь расширять, ведь если потом у тебя появится поле сумма доставки и эта сумма будет входить в состав amout, а твои старые данные в таблице заказа не будут содержать в себе суммы доставки, потом что раньше было не так, то твои данные будут не верны, в то время как динамический подсчет может тебя уберечь от этой участи

Answer (score 0):

Многие движки (наверное подавляющее большинство) интернет-магазинов хранят сумму заказа в таблице заказов. Это избыточность, не соответствует 2нф и гипотетически может привести к неконсистентности. Тут ответственность на программистах, что ПО будет поддерживать сумму в заказе равной сумме по позициям. В классике надо делать транзакционную бд без избыточности, в идеале соответствующую 3нф,и отчётную бд с денормализованными данными, подготовленными для удобных выборок/построения отчётов